# Python3 application icon

Tags: python3

In Ubuntu 13.04, when I use the `setWindowIcon` method in the code of my `python3/pyqt4` application, it works fine, and the application icon is set properly.

After upgrading to Ubuntu 13.10 however, the icon is not changed anymore. Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 13.10 has `python3.3` and `python3.3.m`.

You will be using **python3.3m** to set the application icon properly.